# update_attributes failing to update object in after_save callback (mongomapper+rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I'm having trouble updating a model instance with update_attributes in an after_save callback. Update_attributes returns true, but the attributes aren't getting set in the model instance.

The model object, Graph, has many Datapoints, and I want to keep track of the max value and when it was measured. For various reasons I want to denormalize this info, so I've got the following code:

```
class Graph
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :datapoints, :dependent=>:destroy

  key :max_value, Float
  key :max_value_at, Time
end
```

and in my datapoints:

```
class Datapoint
  belongs_to :graph

  key :graph_id, ObjectId, :required=>true
  key :value, Float
  key :time, Time

  after_save :update_max_on_save

  ....

  def update_max_on_save
    g = self.graph? ? self.graph : Graph.find_by_id(self.graph_id)
    if g.max_value.nil? || g.max_value < self.value
      g.update_attributes( {:max_value=>self.value, :max_value_at=>self.time} )
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone able to shed some light on why this method to update the attributes of the graph would fail?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but I would actually change this to either a `before_save` or `validates :max_is_updated`.

The method you are using in the example, even if it was working, would cause the the object to be saved twice: once when it is originally saved, and again during `update_attributes` in `after_save`.